# How can I select the users which are belonging to group A?

Tags: mysql, symfony

How can I select the users which are belonging to group A?

My tables are below.

my user table.

```
ID | name |sex
1  | bob  |1
2  | kayo |2
3  | ken  |1
```

my fos_group table

```
ID | name
1  | student
2  | teacher
```

my fos_user_user_group

```
user_id | group_id
1       | 1
2       | 2
3       | 1
```

Bob and Ken are belonging to group_1(student)

Kayo is belonging to group_2(teacher)

ex) I can select 'Bob' from user table like this

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
    "SELECT p.name,p.sex
        FROM UserBundle:User p WHERE 
    p.id = '1' );
```

But I would like to select the users which belongs to student group(Bob and Ken)

How should I change the sentence in createQuery?

I just guess I need to join the tables though...

---

additional....

I have tried like this accroding to Fabio's answer

```
    $query = $em->createQuery(
    "SELECT p,p.id,p.username,p.userKey
        FROM UserBundle:User p 
        INNER JOIN fos_user_user_group b
        ON a.ID = b.user_id
        INNER JOIN fos_group c
            ON b.group_id = c.ID
        WHERE c.group_id = '1'");
    $this->data["teachers"] = $query->getResult();
```

but it says

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 94 near 'fos_user_user_group': Error: Class 'fos_user_user_group' is not defined.
```

I guess it means I dont have entity for 'fos_user_user_group'.
I have only entity class for Group and User,other tables were created automatically.

In meanwhile,I used like this in other place in $formmapper.

```
            ->add('teacher',
                null,
                array(
                    'query_builder' =>
                     function (\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $rep) {
                     return $rep->
                    createQueryBuilder('s')
                    ->join('s.groups', 'g') 
                    ->where('g.name = :group')->setParameter('group','TeacherGroup');
                    })

            )
```

it works well,
how can I change this sentence for createQuery()?

Comment: Yes, it's a simple join, any SQL tutorial should show how to do it. What have you tried?

Comment: Hi Barmar thanks for reply ,I attached new sentence in article..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a `INNER JOIN` query

```
SELECT p.name,p.sex
FROM User p 
INNER JOIN fos_user_user_group b
ON a.ID = b.user_id
INNER JOIN fos_group c
ON b.group_id = c.ID
WHERE c.group_id = '1'
```

Comment: I added sentence to my post.  I still need some information, please read article.thanks for your help

Comment: I could solve the problem my code is       "SELECT p,p.id,p.username,p.userKey
            FROM UserBundle:User p 
            INNER JOIN p.groups g
            WHERE g.name = 'teacher'"
thanks ,your answer is big hint!